# I am getting following error This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer.

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, msbuild

I am getting following error This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105.  . I have  

 in my nuget.config file. Is this causing build fail?

Comment: I have following code in nget.config file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
</configuration>

Comment: What version of TFS are you using?